# Android DatePickerDialog Max Date visual bug

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm experiencing a weird visual bug on new DatePickerDialog of Android widgets. I need to set a dialog's selectable date range as 1 month but it shouldn't also select a date from the future. Logic works as expected but the visuals have some sort of bug. Here is how it looks:

[image: Image of Bug]

Note that the "5" is disabled, I cannot select it. However, it looks as selectable. What should I do to solve this issue? Any help is appreciated, thanks. (Today's day of month is also 5, I assume this bug comes from there.)

Edit: This is how I create the dialog.

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public static class DateDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
    {
        private static final long MONTH = 2592000000L;

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            // Use previous selected date in the date picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis(DateUtils.getAtTimeTimestamp(startDate));

            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.AppTheme_DialogTheme, this, year, month, day);
            Date date = new Date(); // get current time

            // get target maximum date which can be 1 month above
            long targetDateTime = DateUtils.getAtTimeTimestamp(startDate) + MONTH;
            if (date.getTime() < targetDateTime)
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(date.getTime()); // now because it can't be future
            else
                dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(targetDateTime); // should also be one month above from the start date.
            dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(DateUtils.getAtTimeTimestamp(startDate));
            return dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2)
        {
            // logic between date selections
        }
    }
```

> DateUtils.getAtTimeTimestamp(String date) basically converts a string to long integer that is time in milliseconds.

Comment: please share your code to show how you created the picker.

Comment: @zipo13 I have edited my code, please check above.

Comment: what is `AppTheme_DialogTheme` ? And Also Describe `getAtTimeTimestamp` method.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Sorry I wrote that wrong at up above, "getAtTimeTimestamp" is the method I'm talking about with the highlighted one. It converts a time string (example: 2018-05-09T12:34:56) to a long value (time in milliseconds). AppTheme_DialogTheme is a theme that makes dialog views fullscreen with a property called "backgroundDimAmount". It extends from "Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light". Edited the question accordingly.